# ServiceStack.redis configuration on VS 2008

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2008, servicestack.redis

I am working on a project(WebAPI) where i have to pick data from azure redis cache and i am using visual studio 2008 due to some constraints. How can i configure it to use ServiceStack.redis/azure redis cache on 08?

I haven't been able to find any solution in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies), the **visual studio 2008 support** the version of **.Net Framework is 3.5**.

While the **ServiceStack.Redis** [dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/) is **.Net Framework 4.5**.

> How can I configure it to use ServiceStack.redis/azure redis cache on 08?

You could try to install the 4.5 version of .Net Framework in Project Properties then you could use [ServiceStack.redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)/azure redis cache.

[image]